# Basic AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm trying to create my first directive. I'm having some challenges. In an attempt to "learn-by-doing", I decided to create a custom HTML element via a directive. My element will allow a user to choose a day of the week. My control template looks like the following:

### myControl.tpl.html

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

### myControl.js

```
angular.module('myControls.dayPicker', [])
    .directive('myDayPicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { value: '=' },
            templateUrl: 'dayPicker/myControl.tpl.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
            }
        };
    });
```

This directive should be reusable across views. To use it, I want to be able to enter the following code:

The selectedDay value will be a value that is on the $scope in my controller. For some reason, I can't seem to get two way binding to work. How do I make it so:

1. The selected day option value gets set to the selectedDay $scope property?
2. How do I automatically set the correct option if the selectedDay is already set?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide Plunker or Fiddle with above mentioned example and issue you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working example which shows how to set a selected day in the controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jrGe/

This uses ng-change to send the data back to a function in the controller:

```
<select ng-model="customSpice" ng-change="spicy(customSpice)">
```

Ignore the references to 'Spicy' stuff... I created this example from one of the fiddles in the AngularJS docs here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Thank you for trying. I got this far. However, I couldn't figure out how to get it in a reusable directive. For instance, I want to be able to add an element to a page that's called my-day-picker. my-day-picker would encapsulate the stuff shown in your fiddle.

Comment: It's SO close. What I'm trying to do is set  $scope.day = "Monday"; in the controller. In this case, the drop down list should have Monday pre-selected. However, I can't figure out how to get it to do that. How do you do that?